# Generate a variable that flags any occurrence of a specific string across multiple variables

Tags: r

Possibly a really simple problem, but my Stata-ingrained brain just can't figure this one out.

I am trying to generate a single 'case-status' variable in R that uses conditional input from multiple variables in a df. I can get it to work conditional on one variable, but am struggling to find a method that includes all variables.

The data looks similar to this:

```
id var1 var2 var3 .....
1 X Y <NA>
2 Y <NA> <NA>
3 <NA> X X
```

I can use `case <- rep(NA, nrow(df))` followed by `case[df$var1 == "X"] <- 1` to return this output:

```
head(case)
[1] 1 NA NA
```

But what I really want to know is if there are *any* instances of X in any of the var variables, so output that looks like this:

```
head(case)
[1] 1 NA 1
```

So how can I change `case[df$var1 == "X"] <- 1` to loop over all 'var' variables (in reality there are about 400 rather than 3)?

Comment: Hi @RHertel - no, that's not it. I don't want to know how many X's there are, I just need to know that there is at least 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a column that finds if any column in a row has an "X", one method using `any`is as follows:

```
# set up example data
df <- data.frame(id=1:3, var1=c("X", "Y", NA), var2=c("Y", NA, "X"), var1=c(NA, NA, "X"),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

df$newVec <- as.integer(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(i) any(i == "X", na.rm=T)))
```

This returns 1s and 0s, if instead you want NAs where every value of the row is NA, use

```
df$newVec <- as.integer(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(i) any(i == "X")))
```

Here is one way in base R to replace all X values with 1s
replacement using a `for` loop

```
for(i in 2:length(df)) df[df[, i] == "X" & !is.na(df[, i]), i] <- 1
```

You have to include `!is.na` in order to ignore the missing values. This should be pretty fast, since its replacement in place.

If you goal is to indicate whether or not a variable has an X, you can use `any` and `sapply`:

```
sapply(df, function(i) any(i == "X"))
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do what I need. I'm not looking to replace my Xs with 1s, but to create a new column in the dataframe that is a flag for 'at least one var* column contains an X'

Comment: So that at least one column contains an X in a given row?

Comment: Yes, the condition should be: At least one column (from subset specified) contains an X.

Comment: See my new (second and third) lines of code. I think this will work.

Comment: Yeah, that works for the example perfectly. I'm just wondering if there's a way to specify the variables by name rather than `df[,-1]` to make this scalable to a more complex dataset. The vars I want to include are consecutively numbered.

Comment: `df[, -1]` says everything but the first variable. To get a vector of the names, you can use `myNames <- grep("regex", names(df), value=T)`. Then, you can use `df[, myNames]` in the same way.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: `myNames <- grep("var", names(df), value=T)`
Then
`df$newVec3 <- as.integer(apply(df[, myNames], 1, function(i) any(i == "X", na.rm=T)))` is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
case <- +!!rowSums(df=="X", na.rm=TRUE) 
case[case==0] <- NA
#> case
#[1]  1 NA  1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("X", "Y"), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(1L, NA, 1L), 
.Label = "Y", class = "factor"), var3 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L), 
.Label = "X", class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "var1", "var2", "var3"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: That looks exactly what I want, but for some reason its giving me:
    > case
    [1] NA NA NA

Will investigate further.

Comment: That's because rowSums needs `na.rm = TRUE`. Have a look at my solution which will return NA only if there is no "X" AND there is at least one NA. Otherwise, in the case of 3 "Y"'s, it would return 0.

Comment: @DominicComtois You're right, thank you. There was a misunderstanding due to R's `NA` and the `<NA>` used in the OP. I updated the post and the data.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
myData <- data.frame(id=1:3, var1=c("X", "Y", NA), 
                     var2=c("Y", NA, "X"), var3=c(NA, NA, "X"),
                     stringsAsFactors=F)

as.numeric(rowSums(myData[2:4] == "X", na.rm=TRUE) > 0)
```

Result:

```
[1] 1 0 1
```

### Edit

To get the exact same results as you did (having NA where no "X" is present but at least one NA is present), try this:

```
ifelse(rowSums(myData[2:4] == "X", na.rm=TRUE) > 0, 1,
       ifelse(rowSums(is.na(myData[2:4])) > 0, NA, 0))
```

Result:

```
[1]  1 NA  1
```

Comment: That could certainly be combined with a secon  if>0 command to get the flag for 'any X'

Comment: Meaning for the presence of NA's? Or just have 1's and 0's ? Pls see my edit.